# RStudio: Error in .jarray(m) : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, out-of-memory, rstudio, rjava

To be able to run the package extraTrees (which i need to make extreme randomised trees) I needed to install the Rjava package in my RStudio. The code below works perfectly when i use it in a limited amount of data (1000 observations..) However i need to be able to run the code on a dataset of 50 000-100 000 observations, an iterate it around 50 times...

```
library(rJava)
library(extraTrees)

et <- extraTrees(Input, Output, ntree = 300 ,nodesize=3, numRandomCuts=2, numThreads= 4)
```

When I try to run this I get the following error:

```
 Error in .jarray(m) : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? I have been looking for an answer but didn't find how to fit it in a RStudio environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Xmx` flag controls the size of the Java runtime heap.  You can increase this to a larger value which may allow your R code to run without hitting the ceiling:

```
> options(java.parameters = "-Xmx4g")     # or 8g, or larger than this, ...
```

Note that this should increase the heap only for the Java process called by your R script.  Outside R, whatever heap size was being used by your Java should remain the same.  You could also change it externally if you wanted to.

I know about `Xmx` but did not know how to do this from within the R console.  For that, I found this useful blog post:

http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/726

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could solve that problem , using:

> options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1024m")

before loading any packages or library.

```
Example:
> options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1024m")
> library(RJDBC)
```